# ¿Las funciones miembro de un objeto "alcanzan" a las variables del objeto?

Tags: c++

Es decir, interiormente, ¿puedo manipualr directamente una variable del objeto, dentro del cuerpo de la función?

¿Esto es equivalente o seria necesario hacerlo con el this siempre?

ISBN tiene las variables miembro n1, n2, n3, y x.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿ No podrías poner el código en lugar de una imagen ? Ya llevas tiempo por aquí, deberías de saber que colocar imágenes no está bien visto, y dificultas a otros usuarios el siquiera entender tu pregunta: con dispositivos móviles (pantallas reducidas), discapacidad visual, ...

Comment: No me permite escribir "Si" como comentario porque es un comentario muy corto pero "Si" es la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Solo cuando tienen exactamente el mismo nombre tendrías que usar `this`. Si el nombre cambia, mayúsculas y minúsculas, un símbolo extra etc... podrías hacer la asignación directa.